# Declaring js object not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, canvas

I am doing a project for school (making a simple game with canvas tag and what not) and i need to use js objects. I have got to the point where i realized that the object would not be "declared" in my main code here is the js file

```
    function Platform(x, y, speed, imgn){
    this.speed=speed;
    //this.img=new Image();
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.imgn=imgn?imgn:parseInt(Math.random()*5);
    /*if(imgn==1){
        img.src="Images/Platform1.png";
    }else if(imgn==2){
        img.src="Images/Platform2.png";
    }else if(imgn==3){
        img.src="Images/Platform3.png";
    }else if(imgn==4){
        img.src="Images/Platform4.png";
    }else if(imgn==5){
        img.src="Images/Platform5.png";
    }*/
}

Platform.prototype.moveUp=function(){
    this.y+=this.speed;
};

Platform.prototype.platdraw=function(){
   ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y) 
};
```

The reason some of it is commented out is bc i though that was breaking it but here is the code where i "declared" it

```
            var Platforms=new Array();
            Platforms.push(new Platform(1, 1, 1, 1));
            alert(Platforms.x)
```

i would greatly appreciate some help also the push statement when ever not commented out would not allow the rest of the code to run

here is the rest of my code in case it is something else wrong for i am not the best at this stuff also ik i can put the object being declared into a loop i just want to test with one atm

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='Platform.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body onload='initialize()'>
        <canvas id='canvas' width='400px' height='500px'></canvas>
        <script>
        var canvas, ctx;

            var onplat , isjump, jumpstage, time;

            var player=new Image();
            player.src="Sprite.png";

            var playerX, playerY, playerXFrame, playerYFrame, playerFrameW, playerFrameH;

            var upKey, leftKey, rightKey;

            function initialize(){
                //canvas variables
                canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
                ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

                //player variables
                playerX=0;
                playerY=0;
                playerXFrame=0;
                playerYFrame=0;
                playerFrameW=34;
                playerFrameH=47;
                onplat=false;
                isjump=false;
                jumpstage=0;
                time=0;


                var Platforms=new Array();
                Platforms.push(new Platform(1, 1, 1, 1));
                alert(Platforms[0])

                //keyboard controls
                upKey=false;
                downKey=false;
                leftKey=false;
                rightKey=false;
                document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
                document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler);

                update();
            }
            function update(){
                time++;
                if(isjump /*&& !onplat*/){

                    if(jumpstage==1 ){
                        playerY-=50;
                        playerYFrame=0;

                        jumpstage++;
                    }else if(jumpstage==2 && time==20){
                        playerY-=20;
                        playerYFrame=0;

                        jumpstage++;
                    }else if(jumpstage==3 && time==30){
                        playerY+=30;
                        playerYFrame=0;

                        jumpstage++;
                    }else if(jumpstage==4 && time==40){
                        playerYFrame=0;
                        playerY+=40;
                        isjump=false;
                        jumpstage=0;

                }} 

                if(rightKey && playerX<canvas.width-playerFrameW-20) {
                    playerYFrame=0;
                    playerX +=6;
                }
                else if(leftKey && playerX>0) {
                    playerYFrame=1;
                    playerX -= 6;
                }
                else if(upKey && playerY>=0 && !isjump){
                    jumpstage=1;
                    onplat=false;
                    playerYFrame=0;
                    playerY-=1;
                    isjump=true;
                    time=0;

                }

                if(rightKey || leftKey || upKey){
                    playerXFrame++;
                    playerXFrame%=6;
                }
                if(!onplat & playerY<400){
                    playerY+=5;
                    if(playerYFrame==0){
                        playerYFrame=0;
                    }else if(playerYFrame==1){
                        playerYFrame=1;
                    }
                }
                if(playerY>410){
                    playerY=400;
                }


                draw();
                requestAnimationFrame(update);

            }
            function draw(){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

                ctx.drawImage(player, playerXFrame*playerFrameW, playerYFrame*playerFrameH, playerFrameW, playerFrameH, playerX, playerY, playerFrameW, playerFrameH );




                console.log(playerX+" "+playerYFrame+" "+playerY+" "+time+" "+isjump);
            }
            function keyDownHandler(e){
                //alert(e.keyCode);
                switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 37: leftKey=true; break;
                    case 38: upKey=true; break;
                    case 39: rightKey=true; break;
                }
            }
            function keyUpHandler(e){
                //alert(e.keyCode);
                switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 37: leftKey=false; break;
                    case 38: upKey=false; break;
                    case 39: rightKey=false; break;
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using Chrome developer tools console to see if some error popped up?

Comment: Don't need to install Chrome just for developer tools, any browser will do

Comment: `Platforms` is an *array* - an array does not have a property called `x` ... did you mean `alert(Platforms[0].x)` to access the pushed Platform object x property?

Comment: @JaromandaX "Chrome" has become a synonym of "browser". Folks don't know, that there are faster and less resource consuming browsers available ...

Comment: @Teemu - I've never considered Chrome to be synonymous with browser, and never will

Comment: @JaromandaX i meant it to be Platform.x must have forgot to change that back when testing out things to fix it also when i do try to push the Platform object nothing works after it

Comment: sure, but `Platform.x` does not exist either, because `Platform` is the class, your only "instance" of that class is in `Platforms[0]`

Comment: @JaromandaX o it worked XD thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following code :

```js
 function Platform(x, y, speed, imgn) {
     this.speed = speed;
     //this.img=new Image();
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.imgn = imgn ? imgn : parseInt(Math.random() * 5);
     /*if(imgn==1){
         img.src="Images/Platform1.png";
     }else if(imgn==2){
         img.src="Images/Platform2.png";
     }else if(imgn==3){
         img.src="Images/Platform3.png";
     }else if(imgn==4){
         img.src="Images/Platform4.png";
     }else if(imgn==5){
         img.src="Images/Platform5.png";
     }*/
 }

 Platform.prototype.moveUp = function() {
     this.y += this.speed;
 };

 Platform.prototype.platdraw = function() {
     ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y)
 };
 var canvas, ctx;

 var onplat, isjump, jumpstage, time;

 var player = new Image();
 player.src = "http://kb4images.com/images/free-images/37032049-free-images.jpg";
 //set image with your image
 var playerX, playerY, playerXFrame, playerYFrame, playerFrameW, playerFrameH;

 var upKey, leftKey, rightKey;

 function initialize() {
     //canvas variables
     canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     //player variables
     playerX = 0;
     playerY = 0;
     playerXFrame = 0;
     playerYFrame = 0;
     playerFrameW = 34;
     playerFrameH = 47;
     onplat = false;
     isjump = false;
     jumpstage = 0;
     time = 0;


     var Platforms = new Array();
     Platforms.push(new Platform(1, 1, 1, 1));
     alert(Platforms[0])

     //keyboard controls
     upKey = false;
     downKey = false;
     leftKey = false;
     rightKey = false;
     document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
     document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler);

     update();
 }

 function update() {
     time++;
     if (isjump /*&& !onplat*/ ) {

         if (jumpstage == 1) {
             playerY -= 50;
             playerYFrame = 0;

             jumpstage++;
         } else if (jumpstage == 2 && time == 20) {
             playerY -= 20;
             playerYFrame = 0;

             jumpstage++;
         } else if (jumpstage == 3 && time == 30) {
             playerY += 30;
             playerYFrame = 0;

             jumpstage++;
         } else if (jumpstage == 4 && time == 40) {
             playerYFrame = 0;
             playerY += 40;
             isjump = false;
             jumpstage = 0;

         }
     }

     if (rightKey && playerX < canvas.width - playerFrameW - 20) {
         playerYFrame = 0;
         playerX += 6;
     } else if (leftKey && playerX > 0) {
         playerYFrame = 1;
         playerX -= 6;
     } else if (upKey && playerY >= 0 && !isjump) {
         jumpstage = 1;
         onplat = false;
         playerYFrame = 0;
         playerY -= 1;
         isjump = true;
         time = 0;

     }

     if (rightKey || leftKey || upKey) {
         playerXFrame++;
         playerXFrame %= 6;
     }
     if (!onplat & playerY < 400) {
         playerY += 5;
         if (playerYFrame == 0) {
             playerYFrame = 0;
         } else if (playerYFrame == 1) {
             playerYFrame = 1;
         }
     }
     if (playerY > 410) {
         playerY = 400;
     }


     draw();
     requestAnimationFrame(update);

 }

 function draw() {
 debugger;
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

     ctx.drawImage(player, playerXFrame * playerFrameW, playerYFrame * playerFrameH, playerFrameW, playerFrameH, playerX, playerY, playerFrameW, playerFrameH);




     console.log(playerX + " " + playerYFrame + " " + playerY + " " + time + " " + isjump);
 }

 function keyDownHandler(e) {
     //alert(e.keyCode);
     switch (e.keyCode) {
         case 37:
             leftKey = true;
             break;
         case 38:
             upKey = true;
             break;
         case 39:
             rightKey = true;
             break;
     }
 }

 function keyUpHandler(e) {
     //alert(e.keyCode);
     switch (e.keyCode) {
         case 37:
             leftKey = false;
             break;
         case 38:
             upKey = false;
             break;
         case 39:
             rightKey = false;
             break;
     }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src='Platform.js'></script>
</head>

<body onload='initialize()'>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='400px' height='500px'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Try to add JS code in separate file and include that file in head. 
Hope it helps :)